# Cannot find name 'PhoneOrOauthTokenResponse' during firebase integration in Angular 13

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created Angular project

```
ng new <projectname>
```

Then installed Angular fire

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

When I compile and run the project

```
ng serve
```

I am seeing the below error

```
Build at: 2022-05-07T07:48:29.607Z - Hash: dcd59b9e5be0333c - Time: 19924ms

Error: node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth-public.d.ts:3137:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PhoneOrOauthTokenResponse'.

3137     _tokenResponse?: PhoneOrOauthTokenResponse;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth-public.d.ts:3429:11 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UserInternal'.

3429     user: UserInternal;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


✖ Failed to compile.
```

My Angular version looks like below. Do I need to degrade the version of Angular?

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.5
Node: 16.15.0
Package Manager: npm 8.5.5
OS: linux x64

Angular: 13.3.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.5
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.5
@angular/cli                    13.3.5
@angular/fire                   7.3.0
@schematics/angular             13.3.5
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.6.4
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. This solution worked:

npm install firebase@9.7.0 --save --save-exact

I got it from:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3217

Comment: The github issue mentions "the issue is in the 'firebase' library, not '@angular/fire'", but I am having the error without using the firebase library in my project. I only use the auth part offered by the '@angular/fire' package.

Answer (score 0):

I started having this problem too after updating eslint packages to the latest.
In my project, downgrading them to these versions solves the compilation errors:

With @angular/fire being on v.7.3.0:

@eslint/eslintrc --> 1.2.2  (problem started on 1.2.3)

eslint --> 8.14.0 (problem started on 8.15.0)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I think it's a problem with version 0.20.

I solve it just running:

```
npm i @firebase/auth@^0.18.3
```